# [_UITableViewSeparatorView rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, runtime-error

I am having a problem in executing the following code while searching in the table. This code works fine elsewhere. But currently it is giving an error as

> [_UITableViewSeparatorView rangeOfString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6041790

Following is the code that is troubling me. Please let me know the bug gidden in there.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
  {
       [tableData removeAllObjects];// remove all data that belongs to previous search
       if([searchText isEqualToString:@""] || searchText==nil)
       {
            [displayTable reloadData];
            return;
       }
    NSInteger counter = 0;
       for(NSString *name in dataSource)
    {
            NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
            NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText];
            if(r.location != NSNotFound)
            {
                if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the names.
                {
                    [tableData addObject:name];
                }
            }
            counter++;
            [pool release];
        }

    [displayTable reloadData];    }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Looking forward to your responses.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're over-releasing the strings that you have stored in dataSource.  I would check any place that you use/create those strings to make sure that you aren't releasing them more times than you should.

Comment: thanks a ton!!..... i did not notice that while coding..... by mistake I chose it to be autorelease while initializing

Answer (score 1):

It means that the memory where the string should reside in memory was freed and there is another object on that place (_UITableViewSeparatorView in your case). Make sure that you are not over-releasing the string in array

You can try to search with NSZombiesEnabled in instruments: [link](http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/)

Comment: thanks a ton!!..... i did not notice that while coding..... by mistake I chose it to be autorelease while initializing

Comment: btw could not accept more than one answer here ...... but thanks your help saved my day!!.... :)

Answer (score 0):

What are you putting in `dataSource`? Evidently, it contains an object that is not an NSString.